# Lost permissions to edit .h files and save xcode6 project

Tags: ios, xcode, permissions, uinavigationcontroller

I have searched all over for an xCode 6 related problem that may inform me to solve my own problems but I haven't found anything helpful.

1. Whenever I embed my Data View Controller into a Navigation Controller, the .h file shows a lock next to it, preventing me from making any edits to the area. When I try, “UINavigationController.h” is currently locked because you are not the owner of the file and do not have write permission" appears. I have the option to press "unlock" but when I do, it directs me to "Could not add write permission to the file because you do not own it. Try modifying the permissions of the file in the Finder or Terminal."
2. As a result, I cannot save my xcode project.
3. When I look at the permssions of the project via "Get Info" in the Finder, my name displays that I have Read & Write privileges.

How can I solve these problems? Please consider that I do not have much experience with these matters, which may already be obvious based on my question. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Open a console, navigate to xcode project path and try use this command: `chmod 777 -R .` with this command you give all permission at all files. If you want change the permission only of one file use: `chmod 777 path_file`

Comment: Don't do a 777 permission to a whole dir. just my 2 cents